# Lost volume data of water and isopropanol mixtures

Tags: mass, physical-chemistry, density, volume

WHO has two recipes for disinfecting, based on ethanol and isopropanol (IPA). They typically start with an alcohol volume and then top it off with the other ingredients to 10 litre. One of the recipes is based on 75% v/v IPA. Because 75% IPA volume plus 25% volume of other ingredients (mainly water) is less than 100% volume, it is not known how much water should be added. For ethanol based disinfectant I could construct a mass based recipe. However, I cannot find volume/volume and mass/mass relations for isopropanol and water mixtures. I've published this [here](https://vanderworp.org/en/universal-disinfectant-for-coronavirus-covid-19/). Is there anyone who can help so that the second WHO recipe can also be converted to mass units?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe the WHO did not consult a chemist in preparing this recipe? I would assume they know what they are doing here

Comment: I am not sure why you suggest I believe that? The only thing I want is to create more practical, small scale, additional recipes based on both mass and volume. Definite without altering the composition, although not relevant to the question.

Comment: The effect you're worrying about is minimal. By and large the volumes of alcohol and glycerine are very additive. You're worrying about nada.

Comment: Indeed I neglected the effect between alcohol and glycerol. However, I don't want to neglect this effect between alcohol and water. "Because volume is lost by adding water" is edited.

Comment: The practical effect is minimal (the WHO paper says peak antiseptic activity is in the 70-80% range), but it is still a reasonable physics question.

Comment: I ended up adding not 250 ml but 273 ml of water plus 750 ml IPA for 1 litre. As a rough approach, three given densities for 50%, 70% and 100% v/v were used, together with a measurement of volume and weight in kitchen conditions for 75% v/v. Using a function as rough approach, density (g/ml) =-0.000022667*x^2+0.00072*x+0.94067 for 50% to 100%, which is very close to my measurement of 0.863 g/ml for 75% v/v IPA. Information has been added to the link mentioned in the question.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you need the high precision that you are implying.  7.5 liters of isopropanol and 2.5 liters of water should get you close enough.

Comment: We agree on that. However, I want to stay as close to the WHO recipe as possible because it is a proven solution. Apparently many people started making their own disinfectant because of scarcity, so I feel it a responsibility to do it as best as possible.

Comment: @bukris, if you need to err on the side of caution, use a bit more isopropanol.  Bacteria and viruses are killed by things that they can't adapt to, so a higher concentration of a denaturant is in the safe direction.

Comment: @DavidWhite, I don't use the recipe myself. My personal favorite: 75% EtOH + 10% IPA. That matches your thought. If you apply enough on your hands, alcohol evaporates faster and there is always a point with sufficient water concentration to make cell walls permeable to the alcohol. You see this combination in many commercial hospital products. For example, see [this example with even more IPA](https://vanderworp.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/example_disinfection_hospital_grade-1152x1536.jpg). IPA dissolves fats better than EtOH, which may be a reason to use it in combination.

Answer (score 1):

A 75% v/v IPA water mixture has a density of somewhere around 0.863 - 0.865 g/ml.

Based on some collected points [(sources and explanation)](https://vanderworp.org/en/universal-disinfectant-for-coronavirus-covid-19) a function approximates density "d" (g/ml) for percentages "x" between 0% and 100% v/v. Expect an error margin around 1%.

$$ d = - {7.1276e^{-8}x^3} - {4.8771e^{-7}x^2} - {1.3884e^{-3}x} + 1.0015 $$